# Antenna cable pin-out identification

Tags: signal, antenna, radio, frequency-modulation, stereo

I am trying to connect a stock car FM/AM antenna with a new aftermarket stereo system, Turns out my car antenna has 2 wires. One is Co-axial cable for signal (Most probably) and there's one more single cable comes along with it. Which I have no idea what's its for.

PS. I have tried hooking signal cable But all I got is complete static. I have also tried grounding the other extra cable with no luck.

`Moreover When I connected a bare 2 meter copper wire directly to the antenna core. It gained some signal. But that is a inefficient solution to this I wanted to use my Stock car antenna to have a strong reception`

> The image below is similar to my cable only difference is that I have a Yellow color cable in place of blue

Also my stereo has only one hole for Co-axial cable. And no place for the other cable.

[image: generic similar cable as I am having]

My Car Name : Maruti Suzuki Baleno

My Stereo : Sony DSX-A100U

Anyone Please put a light what I am doing wrong here. And tell me how to hook this antenna to my stereo.

Comment: After you plugged in the cable, did you make sure the other side was clipped in tightly to the antenna feed?

Comment: Most likely the extra wire is to provide power to an amplifier in the base of the antenna.  Many car radios have a connection to power the antenna.  Look at table of connections on your radio, and you should find something.

Comment: @BlairFonville yes, everything was clipped correctly , even i double checked it via multi meter also